# How can I get the right selector in ARM assembly

Tags: objective-c, ida

When I open the iOS framework AddressBook with IDA, I get the following code:

```
**__ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook__
var_C= -0xC
PUSH            {R7,LR}
MOV             R7, SP
SUB             SP, SP, #4
MOVW            R1, #0x2B06
MOV.W           R12, #0
MOVT.W          R1, #0xB
STR.W           R12, [SP,#0xC+var_C]
ADD             R1, PC
LDR             R1, [R1]
BLX             _objc_msgSend
ADD             SP, SP, #4
POP             {R7,PC}
; End of function __ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook__**
```

How can get to know what selector is stored in R1 before _objc_msgSend() called.

With some help from Internet, I do the following things:

1. After MOVW R1, #0x2B06 and MOVT.W R1, #0xB, I got the R1=0x000B2B06
2. After ADD R1, PC, I got R1=0x000B2B06+PC(A13A)+4=0x000BCC44, where A13A is the address of ADD R1, PC
3. the content near that address is:

   __objc_selrefs:000BCC44                 DCD aInitasaddres_0     ; "initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withS"...
   __objc_selrefs:000BCC48                 DCD aDefaultstylepr     ; "defaultStyleProviderForStyle:"
   __objc_selrefs:000BCC4C                 DCD aInitwithnaviga     ; "initWithNavigationController:"
   __objc_selrefs:000BCC50                 DCD aSetupinitialst     ; "setupInitialStackAndLoadState:"

So I got the selector "initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withS...",

4.But when I log the workflow I got that "setupInitialStackAndLoadState:" was actually called.

Is there anything wrong with my method to get the selector?

Comment: It makes sense for "initAsAddressBook" method to call another "initAsAddressBook" selector. Why do you think this call goes to "setupInitialStackAndLoadState"? How do you "log the workflow"?

Comment: I use MSMessageHook to add the log at the beginning and the end of every method, including "initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withS...". When the app run, I got the following log:  started: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook_
started: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_setupInitialStackAndLoadState_
...finished: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook_and no started: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook_withStyle_ appeared in the log file!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a bug or a timing issue with your logging tool. It's clearly calling `initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withStyle:`. Here's what IDA 6.3 shows (a somewhat different build, it seems):

```
__text:000014A8       PUSH            {R7,LR}
__text:000014AA       ADD             R7, SP, #0
__text:000014AC       SUB             SP, SP, #4
__text:000014AE       LDR             R1, =(selRef_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook_withStyle_ - 0x14BA)
__text:000014B0       SXTB            R2, R2
__text:000014B2       MOV.W           R12, #0
__text:000014B6       ADD             R1, PC ; selRef_initAsAddressBook_withAddressBook_withStyle_
__text:000014B8       STR.W           R12, [SP,#4+var_4]
__text:000014BC       LDR             R1, [R1]          ; "initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withS"...
__text:000014BE       BLX             _objc_msgSend
__text:000014C2       SUB.W           SP, R7, #0
__text:000014C6       POP             {R7,PC}
```

The `setupInitialStackAndLoadState` selector is called later in `initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withStyle:`.

Comment: But in my log file, the method initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withStyle: is not called. What is called is initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:. So maybe what you said "The setupInitialStackAndLoadState selector is called later in initAsAddressBook:withAddressBook:withStyle:" makes no sense!